# How to display bootstrap 3 navbar menu items horizontally on collapse

Tags: jquery, css, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap 3 navbar witch is set to collapse on a min with of 1295px.
When it collapses and I click on the button, I want it to display the menu items horizontally and not vertically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do something like

```
 <style>
@media ( max-width:1295px) {
.yourmenu{
 //do your css coding here, you may tweak the margin, padding, float of your menu

 }
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the media query and modified the `.dropdown` class in the media query